# check if the id of a image exist in a list separated by comma in another table

Tags: mysql

i Have two tables slider and gallery . In gallery i have images uploaded by `id` as primary key .  I am making a slider in which when i create a slider and select the images it stores the image id selected for that slider in the slider table inside `images_ids` as a list separated by comma. Now the thing is i wanted to make a query in which i get all the images and i specify my slider id and if that image is in my slider id it says present and for other which are not says not . I have attached a sql fiddle for my tables and sample data too . Please suggest me how can i accomplish this .

The output i expect is something like this

```
image_id slider_id images_id   status


  1         1        1,4       present

  2         1        1,4        not 

  3         1        1,4        not 

  4         1        1,4       present
```

in above the `image_id` is from gallery table which is `id` in there . and rest of them are from slider table apart from the status which i would like to create .

My [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8427/1)

Comment: Don't store comma separated values. Create a proper 1:n relationship  and your query gets really easy. And why does the table have another `image_id` column?

Answer (score 0):

The following query kind of works **BUT** will give you issues when the gallery.id reaches into the teens. For instance a gellery.id of 1 and a slider.images_id that contains 11, 12, 13, etc.

```
SELECT
 `gallery`.`id` AS image_id
 ,`sliders`.`id` AS slider_id
 ,`sliders`.`images_id`
 ,(CASE
    WHEN instr(`sliders`.`images_id`,`gallery`.`id`) != 0 THEN 'present'
    ELSE 'not'
   END)AS status
FROM `gallery`, `sliders`
```

You could get around this by surrounding each ID in the images_id with a , then in the case statement add the , as a delimiter surrounding the image_id:

```
INSERT INTO `sliders` (`id`, `name`, `images_id`, `creation_date`)
VALUES (4, 'Hello', ',5,6,', '1394233227');

instr(`sliders`.`images_id`,CONCAT(',',`gallery`.`id`,','))
```

**HOWEVER**, this is may not be ideal.  I think you will probably be better off using a table between the two existing tables to define the many to many relationship (an image can be in many sliders and a slider can have many images).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery_sliders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gallery_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slider_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `gallery_sliders` (`gallery_id`, `slider_id`) VALUES
(5,4),
(6,4),
(5,6),
(6,6),
(2,7),
(1,7);

SELECT
 `gallery`.`id`
 ,`gallery`.`image_url`
 ,`sliders`.`id`
 ,`sliders`.`name`
 ,`sliders`.`creation_date`
FROM `sliders`
INNER JOIN `gallery_sliders` ON `sliders`.`id` = `gallery_sliders`.`slider_id`
INNER JOIN `gallery` ON `gallery`.`id` = `gallery_sliders`.`gallery_id`
ORDER BY `gallery`.`id`, `sliders`.`id`;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I thought of this that this approach may give trouble if it reaches to teens . But i thought there might a solution i am not aware of . I think i should drop this idea . But your reply was def helpful and right too if in terms we add a delimiter .